# KDE Dolphin change user when in ssh folder?

Tags: ssh, dolphin

I am trying to use KDE Dolphin to access a server over SSH.

My .ssh/config contains this:

```
Host myhost
HostName my-linux-server-name.somewhere.nl
User myuser
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/KEY_ssh_private_openssh
ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p shell
```

I can login on the commandline using `ssh myhost` then change to user "www-data" with the commands `sudo su` and `su www-data` and then edit files.

Now I want to do the same with KDE Dolphin.
I can login with Dolphin if I go to `fish://myuser@myhost`.
I can also see files, but I cannot copy any files to this server because the user "myuser" has no write-permissions on the server.

Is there a way to use Dolphin as a different user than the ssh-user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am right, the Dolphin will use SFTP to access the files on the remote server and SFTP protocol implemented by OpenSSH does not have any support for permission escalation.

You should fix your permissions on that server or connect using a user who has access to the files you are interested in.

Comment: Dolphin can use sftp, but if I go to ```fish://...```, I would expect that the "fish" protocol is used (Files Transferred over SHell). I cannot find any information that suggests that Dolphin switches over to the sftp protocol.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. But the fish protocol does not seem to support privilege escalation either, at least what I could find: http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/mc/mc/vfs/README.fish?view=markup

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, dolphin has to be launched from the user your trying to have the permissions on. But that would mean to grant that user permission to edit, read and or write maybe if you make that user as a whole have the permissions would make for less complications, doing something like a

```
sudo chown user:usergroup --recursive -vf /path/of/file/or/folder
```

*Sidenote: since you can't do sudo dolphin, i don't think you can make it have its own permissions, not sure if creating the user dolphin would help, i know this might not solve your issue but there's my input*